# Unity3d 5 Direct Input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an issue in Unity3d v5 where my joystick does not work as intended, When i plug in the joystick, moving it right from the center, gives me -1 and up to 1. 
Keeping it completely center, gives me 1 and moving it left gives me 1 (so no change in value moving stick left.
From what ive read it has to do with using RawInput and not using DirectInput.
I have read a post where someone suggests using a registry change to force unity to use directinput. But it does nothing for me using unity3d v5.

Can anyone please help me, because i am completely stuck on this and getting this joystick to work is essential for my game :)

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to find any information about this issue from an official Unity source, but take a look at the answer here: [Joystick not working](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/852298/joystick-not-working.html?sort=oldest)
And follow through the threads referred to there. The upshot of this all is that RawInput is all you can rely on for joystick input, on windows.  The best solution to this problem I can think of is runtime calibration in your game/app.  If you don't care to implement that yourself, there are 3rd party options such as this one, that integrate with Unity: [cInput 2](http://cinput2.weebly.com/)

I am running into this same problem with my Unity projects, and my plan is simply to present joystick users with the option to calibrate.  You could save the calibration settings so the user doesn't have to calibrate every time the game is run.  Not ideal, but again the most realistic solution to the problem I can come up with.